# Where to find Emacs Helm documentation

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs-helm

[Helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm) is a great framework for selection and autocompletion. Reading [Anything page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Anything) on [Emacs Wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/), I know Helm evolved from Anything. The page advises user to update extensions written for Anything to be used with Helm but provided no instruction on how to do. [Helm wiki](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/wiki) doesn't provide any helpful information on writing extensions using Helm framework (it's not even user-editable, contains grammatical errors that no one fixes or pull requests are not accepted, which I find really unwelcome). I've been extensively using Helm recently and like it a lot, and I want to write a cheatsheet (similar to the excellent [Clojure cheatsheet](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/clojure-cheatsheet)) to serve my workflow better. So my questions are:

- Is the (outdated) Anything documentation applicable to current Helm?  And how compatible is it?
- Is there any useful documentation about Helm which explains how it works and how to write extensions using it?  I've been Googling for a while but I couldn't find anything helpful enough.

I'm a Lisper and I don't mind reading source code at all.  However, it's a time-consuming process so I just want to look for all the available information first before deciding to dig into the source code.

Comment: +1 mainly to slightly compensate for the wanton close vote.

Comment: Reading both Stack Overflow's [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) pages several times, I don't think my question is inappropriate. Or is it?

Comment: ask the helm list: http://news.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.helm.user

Comment: BTW, I usually take a look at an existing source which is similar to what I want to do and use it as a template

Comment: Hi there, anything new ? It would be awesome if you could write such cheatsheet.

Comment: @Ehvince I have fairly grasped the idea of how Helm works now.  I didn't have time to document it but will come back in several days. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: Hello ! Did you write your documentation ? :)

Answer (score 8):

As far as writing new extensions for helm I would recommend the 16 minute video that accompanies this: https://github.com/krisajenkins/helm-spotify

Comment: awesome tutorial.  Mentions M-x helm-describe-helm-attribute ... aka keys for the alists that define sources.

Answer (score 8):

Regarding Helm daily use, check [A Package in a league of its own](https://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html)

Answer (score 8):

A very good tutorial was written by John Kitchin: 
http://wikemacs.org/wiki/How_to_write_helm_extensions

(first of the three original post blogs: http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2015/01/24/Anatomy-of-a-helm-source/)

He introduces:

- the simplest kind of helm interface with a fixed set of candidates
- A simple dynamic set of candidates
- A simple fixed set of candidates from a list of cons cells.
- Candidates and one action
- More than one action
- Handling multiple selections
- Actions when there is no match

This is much appreciated, thanks John !

Answer (score 1):

The latest helm wiki is https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/wiki. That could be usefull for emacs helm users.

Comment: The documentation is badly written, outdated, not taken care, incomplete and doesn't allow community edit :-(.